# stop a matlab script execution at a particular line after it has been launched

Tags: matlab

I have a matlab script which takes 2days to compelte due to 4 batch sims written one after the other in the script.

Now since its too slow I planned to run each batch sim separately in another matlab session (to parallelise 4 batch jobs)

However since I have already launched the script with all 4 batches, is there a way to stop the ongoing execution at a particular line?  (ex. where my batch1 run ends ).

Thanks,
yvk

Answer (score 0):

In R2016+ you can add a breakpoint while the script is running.

Comment: Thanks for the reply aksadv, should I first pause and then add breakpoints ?

Comment: I don't think that pausing the script is necessary.